# search for backslash

Tags: javascript, backslash

I've JavaScript which searches for eg. a letter in a string and outputs "ok" if the letter is not there and "not ok" if the letter is there:

```
 var term = "term";
 var slash = "a";
 var search =term.search(slash);

 if(search==-1)
 "ok";
 else
 "not ok";
```

The problem is that I want this to work with a backslash too.
The strange thing is, searching for 2 backslashes in a row works, so "term" outputs "ok" and "term\\" outputs "not ok":

```
 var term = "term";
 var slash = "\\\\";
 var search =term.search(slash);

 if(search==-1)
 "ok";
 else
 "not ok";
```

But searching for 1 backslash doesn't work, so this code gives an error:

```
 var term = "term";
 var slash = "\\";
 var search =term.search(slash);

 if(search==-1)
 "ok";
 else
 "not ok";
```

Hope someone sees the error. Thanks!

Comment: Have you noticed that all you `term` Varaiables doesn't contain backslashes??

Comment: So how are you searching for something that does not exist?

Comment: It's an example, in my examples, the output would be "ok"...since the var search outputs -1 (since there is no backslash in the var term).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two layers of interpretation involved with making a regular expression in JavaScript.  The first is that of the *string* syntax, and you've correctly doubled your backslashes to account for that. However, the string will itself be interpreted by the regular expression syntax analysis code, and *that* will have a problem with a single lone backslash. In other words, a regular expression consisting of a single backslash is a syntax error; it's simply not allowed. If you want to search for a single backslash, you need a regular expression with two backslashes in it.

Making a regular expression with the native literal regular expression syntax makes this more obvious:

```
var r1 = /\\/; /* this is OK */
var r2 = /\/;  /* this is not OK */
```